# System randomly freezes; unable to access terminal; restart fixes for a couple days

Tags: kernel, shutdown, freeze, systemd, canonical-livepatch

I'm having this weird issue where after a while, my system just locks up. None of the `CTRL+ALT+F*` keys bring up the terminal or login, and only after a restart do things work again. During the time when things are locked up, I can't connect to any of my Docker containers or via SSH. Right now, all it runs is SSH and Docker on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I use it mostly headlessly, but I've had an inactive SSH connection to the machine for the past couple days. The very last logs were that it was starting livepatch via snap. I thought livepatch was supposed to avoid shutdowns. Could this be the cause? Logs follow.

Here's a dump from `journalctl -b -1 -e`: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/5ScX6qPsMJ/

There is nothing in `/var/crash`.

Memory and swap information:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        98970988     5630200    90493816       47532     2846972    92464004
Swap:        2097148           0     2097148
```

Looking for ideas. Happy to provide further logs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much RAM do you have? How much SWAP? The `free` command will tell you. Read `man free mkswap swapon`.

Comment: @waltinator Updated the question with RAM/SWAP information. Looks like there is a lot available, though I can't speak for what happened during the problem this morning.